# Push Notification in android has been Denied

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I Send Push notifications to the users
the users are less than 1,00,000
But most of the users are not getting the notifications. Is google Denying my notifications.
I am only sending a single notification per month.
is there any way to know about it?
Please Help me in sorting out this issue

Comment: there is limit that a single notification can be simultaneously sent to 1000 receipents. I dont know any other limitations like 100000 users limitation or daily limitations but i might be wrong

Comment: I am sending only one by one